# Constructor por defecto, ¿valores null y cero?

Tags: java, constructor, null

Tengo una duda sobre los constructores por defecto, ¿que valor da a los atributos? si tengo por ejemplo el siguiente código:

```
int numero;
String texto;

public Constructor(){
}
```

Tendrán estos valores, es decir, inicializa a cero y a null:

```
numero = 0;

texto = null;
```

Otra duda que tengo seria y si tengo un objeto como atributo, ¿como se inicializará? es decir que fuese una clase compuesta.

Comment: String en Java es una clase,  por lo que te estás respondiendo a ti mismo. El valor por defecto de los atributos que son objetos es NULL (por si no lo había dejado claro).

Comment: Efectivamente, ahora lo que dices, String no es un tipo de dato primitivo.

Answer (score 8):

Si tienes no inicializas las variables, todas tendrán su valor por defecto, que son los siguientes:

```
+---------+---------+
|  Tipo   |  Valor  |
+---------+---------+
| byte    | 0       |
| short   | 0       |
| int     | 0       |
| long    | 0L      |
| float   | 0.0f    |
| double  | 0.0d    |
| char    | ‘u0000’ |
| object  | null    |
| boolean | false   |
+---------+---------+
```

`String`, en Java es una clase, por lo que su valor por defecto será `null`.

[Fuente](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Answer (score 0):

Lo que preguntas se puede ejemplificar de la siguiente manera:

```
public class Persona {

  private int edad;
  private String nombre;
  private Double altura;
  private Boolean flag;

  public Persona() {

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     Persona pers = new Persona();
     System.out.println(pers.edad);
     System.out.println(pers.nombre);
     System.out.println(pers.altura);
     System.out.println(pers.flag);
  }

}
```

Si colocas o no el constructor vacío, se crea uno por defecto, al instanciar la clase el output seria el siguiente:

[image: Output]